# working with filenames and scheduled function calls in javascript

Tags: javascript, perl, scheduled-tasks

I have a couple questions about javascript:

1. Does javascript have the capability to identify a filename with a timestamp as a name?

Similar to the Perl code below utilizing the POSIX module?

```
my $filepath = sprintf("/path/to/file%s.JSON",strftime("%y%m%d",localtime));
```

this is just an example. I would like to find file in format `yy/mm/dd/hh/min`

For example say I want to find a file with the name `12_11_03_15:15.json` how can I do this with javascript.

1. Say I create a function that I want to trigger every 15 minutes to read the file how is this possible with javascript? I looked at `setInterval()` but that won't work because it is dependent on when the browser is launched. Is it possible to schedule a function to execute every hh:00, hh:15, hh:30, hh:45?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Date class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to get information about the current time.

To schedule a function to run at a certain time, `setInterval()` is indeed the best choice. It seems like what you're really looking for is a way to find out when to start the first interval such that it will fall on a quarter-hour. For that, you should again use Date to get the current time and subtract it from the next quarter-hour; you can use the resulting value with setTimeout to time the start of the first interval.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/GSF6C/3/

```
var nextQuarterHour = new Date();
nextQuarterHour.setMilliseconds(0);
nextQuarterHour.setSeconds(0);

do {
   nextQuarterHour.setMinutes(nextQuarterHour.getMinutes() + 1);
} while (nextQuarterHour.getMinutes() % 15)

var millisecondsToNextQuarterHour = nextQuarterHour.getTime() - Date.now();

document.write(millisecondsToNextQuarterHour);

setTimeout(function () {
    alert("Ding!");
    setInterval(function () { alert("Dong!"); }, 15 * 60 * 1000);
}, millisecondsToNextQuarterHour);
```

​
​

Comment: There is a problem with this because the first interval will also be the next one. 'setInterval' keeps on running a function. Check out 'setTimeout' which only executes a function once then set another timeout in that function based on the current time.

Comment: @Shikyo Perhaps you misunderstood me? I did indeed prescribe setTimeout to delay the setup of the interval.

Comment: What about reading a file with timestamp as a name? Thank you for the function call solution.

Comment: @user843796, that was what my first sentence was meant to address. If you follow the link you will find methods that you can use on a Date object (you can get one corresponding to the current time with simply `new Date()`) to get the current minutes, month, etc. You can `+` those to a string and they will automatically be coerced to a string - for instance, if you are constructing a file path. Note that most of the values are 0-based. For instance, the days of the week go from 0 to 6.